# value of state is always default. React js 16.12.0

Tags: reactjs, setstate, use-effect

I have two useEffect-s. One is used to fetch data from api and save it in the state and second is called only once and it starts listening to websocket event.
In the websocket event handler I log the fetched data but it always has the default value.
Even though fetching data completes successfully and the list is drawn on UI, the value of list is always empty - [].

```
const [list, setList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   axios.get("https://sample.api.com/get/list")
       .then(res => {
           setList(res.data);
       });
}, [window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]]);

useEffect(() => {
   webSocket.on('messageRecieved', (message) => {
        console.log(list);
    }); 
}, []);
```

Comment: Yes the `console.log` inside the event will always show the initial value, what do you want to do when you receive an event? if you just want to log the list to see if it's updated from the fetch put a `console.log` inside the component body or check the react devtools

Comment: The problem is the initial value, after setList() call, I want to retrieve the newly assigned value with the list variable and not initial. But Draeken's answer looks promising, I will check it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second effect is referencing the initial list value (an empty array) due to closure. This is why useEffect should reference all of its dependencies in its second argument.

But in this case, where you don't want to subscribe to the webSocket event each time the list is updated, you could use React's refs on the list.

```js
const listValue = useRef([]);
const [list, setList] = useState(listValue.current);
```

When setting the value:

```js
res => {
    listValue.current = res.data
    setList(listValue.current);
}
```

And when retrieving the list in a one time fired useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    webSocket.on('messageRecieved', (message) => {
       console.log(listValue.current);
    }); 
}, []);
```

Comment: This was that I was looking for, perfect and exact solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
.then(res => {
```

to

```
.then((res) => {
```

Would clarify if you added console logs to each hook or said if the values are preset in them:

```
useEffect(() => {
   axios.get("https://sample.api.com/get/list")
       .then((res) => {
           console.log(res.data)
           setList(res.data);
       });
}, [window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]]);

useEffect(() => {
   webSocket.on('messageRecieved', (message) => {
        console.log(list);
        console.log(message);
    }); 
}, []);
```

You could also add error catch, just in case:

```
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response)
})
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not specific. even the 'messageRecieved' is triggered after a minute, the list is still default. While for surely the  setList(res.data); is called and nonempty list was passed to it.

Comment: How does putting parenthesis around the argument change anything? I didn't realize this was anything other than cosmetic.

Comment: Thank you for contribution but Draeken's answer was the solution to my problem.